# Can't push to Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, git-lfs, bonobo

I originally had this project stored in Git Hub but wanted to set up a local Bonobo server to avoid storage issues.  However, when was setting up a Bonobo Git Server and tried

```
git push -u origin master
```

I got:

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/100), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: Repository or object not found: http://admin@192.168.1.35/Bonobo.Git.Server/SnowGame.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.1.35/Bonobo.Git.Server/SnowGame.git'
```

And I was unable to push to the repository.

Sorry, I am very new to this and couldn't find any solutions.

Does the lfs system have to be configured on a Bonobo server?